# MySQL if result null change query

Tags: mysql

what if I have two strings: "123" and "abc". I want to select username if there's username "123" then choose it, if not found (null) then select username where "abc"

I have a table called USERS, this table responsibility with workflow engine account. I want to show columns in USERS:

1. `username`
2. `email`
3. `usr_firstname`
4. `usr_lastname`

I am using `concat` to merge column 3 and 4 with space between it. In the office, there are 2 types of employee:

1. `origin/internal employee`
2. `outsource/partner employee`

Origin employee login into every system using LDAP (`FirstName.LastName`), but outsource or partner employee login individually just for our workflow engine using employee identity number.

In this case, if I use something like:

`Where username = 'employeenumber' or username = 'LDAPacc'` the result is both account (used and unused for outsource) they appear. I want to show just 1 rows and 1 query but it's work with internal or even outsource (they will got data correctly for outsource).

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. What you have tried, plz show us. And also elaborate on your question. Your title is not clear.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I have already edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found when I tested my logic to mysql tryit editor by w3schools and It's worked properly what I need. Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 'zz' OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 'zz') AND CustomerID = '3')
```

let's say CustomerID is equivalent to my username column, then I tried to swap 'zz' and '3' value and it's still works. I hope there's more simple query than this

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this query;

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  username IN ('123', 'abc')
AND    (username='123' OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE username='abc'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use COALESCE.

COALESCE selects the first non null value out of the ones supplied.
So you could use....

```
SELECT COALESCE(String_123, string_ABC);
```

If string_123 has a value it will select that, otherwise it will select string_ABC unless of course they are both null.

So to be safe include a default value.......

```
SELECT COALESCE(String_123, string_ABC, string_Default);
```

Comment: I've edit my question for more clear, maybe you can check